# Using my Baofeng UV-5R to talk to walkie talkies

Tags: united-states, legal, ht, frs

I have a few walkie talkies at home and sometimes I connect my UV-5R to them to talk to them and act as another walkie talkie. At one time, I built a little simplex repeater out of it. Should I not be doing this? I don't think the other walkie talkie users care about me doing this, just knowing the FCC, they might freak out or something crazy.

I used the 462.562 frequency.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The GMRS and FRS bands are governed by the FCC and have [specific requirements](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e593ed9f147a6ee87a8803d05b9667c9&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title47/47cfr95_main_02.tpl) not just for use and power output, but for equipment that is allowed.  One of the requirements is that radios used for GMRS service be [part 95](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e593ed9f147a6ee87a8803d05b9667c9&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title47/47cfr95_main_02.tpl) certified and FCC certified for GMRS use:

> §95.129   Station equipment.
>
> Every station in a GMRS system must use transmitters the FCC has certificated for use in the GMRS. Write to any FCC Field Office to find out if a particular transmitter has been certificated for the GMRS. All station equipment in a GMRS system must comply with the technical rules in part 95.

The FRS rules are just as strict:

> §95.194   (FRS Rule 4) FRS units.
>
> (a) You may only use an FCC certified FRS unit. (You can identify an FCC certified FRS unit by the label placed on it by the manufacturer.)
>
> (b) You must not make, or have made, any internal modification to an FRS unit. Any internal modification cancels the FCC certification and voids your authority to operate the unit in the FRS.
>
> (c) You may not attach any antenna, power amplifier, or other apparatus to an FRS unit that has not been FCC certified as part of that FRS unit. There are no exceptions to this rule and attaching any such apparatus to a FRS unit cancels the FCC certification and voids everyone's authority to operate the unit in the FRS.
>
> (d) FRS units are prohibited from transmitting data in store-and-forward packet operation mode.

The FCC does not have a process to self-certify radios, so you can't declare the radio certified.  If you have an Amateur Radio license you'll find that the FRS and GMRS frequencies aren't available under that license.

So according to FCC rules, your use of the UV-5R is not acceptable on that frequency.

Answer (score 7):

Before getting my ham license I used MURS on my baofeng with no problems because there is simply no MURS traffic in my area. If I were still an unlicensed operator then I would still be using MURS with my baofeng UV-5R. But once you get the Technician license the penalties go way up (or at least the enforcement) and a ham doesn't need to use MURS anyway.

GMRS is a whole different story. Although there is almost never any GMRS traffic in my area, there is a licensed local GMRS operator who has nothing better to do than monitor the GMRS only channels of bubble pack radios and rudely scold unlicensed users. While I appreciate his zeal, I think he goes about things the wrong way. Instead of yelling and threatening unlicensed users, usually teenage kids, he should be trying to get them licensed so that he'd have someone to talk to! I think he's the main reason GMRS is dead in this area.

I chose to get my Technician license solely because it was way cheaper than getting a GMRS license. And I'm glad I did because it gave me access to local repeaters and taught me a ton about VHF radio.

I can't recommend using a Baofeng radio on FRS frequencies because technically its illegal. But if you stay on the FRS only frequencies, 467.562 for example (not 462.562 as you stated), then I doubt anyone will notice. The FRS only frequencies are Channels 8 thru 14 on the bubble pack radios.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use it to communicate with any standard walkie talkies, whether they use CB, FRS, GMRS, or MURS.

Everything has been addressed except the MURS & CB ones(well, one did but they got it wrong, no offense.)

This is a pretty good website if you want a detailed explanation of why you can't use MURS https://sites.google.com/site/mursradio2/mursradiocertificationforpart95

To sum it up, it has to be MURS Part 95 certified or be grandfathered in, of which the Baofeng is neither.

Of course CB uses way different frequencies but I'll tell why it isn't legal, in case it helps someone. It has to be certified and it has to be able to operate on ONLY the CB channels.

Comment: "Cannot" is a strong word, don't you think, when in fact is is absolutely possible (except for CB) but merely subject to a regulation that is de facto unenforced?

Comment: You are correct. If you use a Baofeng on the 1 watt setting for MURS, you cannot be detected as illegal. Even if you were to crank the power it is extremely doubtful someone would find you, and then would anyone care? I've been listening to MURS just to see if anything popped up and it is completely silent.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the MURS frequencies. These are license free.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Use_Radio_Service

Comment: Hmm? The baofeng UV-5R is dual band and most certainly does cover MURS, which is an acceptable choice if you want a commercial "walkie-talkie" to be able to talk to an amateur radio. If you're stuck with FRS/GMRS then that's fine too, FRS is also licence-free (but GMRS is not).

Comment: @DanKD2EE You're right, I was getting my bands mixed up.

Comment: MURS frequencies are only available for use by "type-accepted MURS equipment", not any radio able to transmit on those frequencies. the UV-5R is not type accepted for MURS use so it is not an acceptable choice for MURS (or FRS/GMRS use).